# How to fix my Clear button to remove array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I really need help with getting my button's onclick to clear. struggling to understand how I can clear the array names once they have been inputted. I've only recently been studying Javascript and my knowledge in Html is only mediocre.

```js
function Add() {
  //create a para obj
  var newPara = document.createElement("p");

  //create the text content
  var input = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
  var newText = document.createTextNode(input);

  //attach the text to the para obj
  newPara.appendChild(newText);

  //attach the para obj to the div obj
  var myDiv = document.getElementById("result");
  myDiv.appendChild(newPara);
}

function Clear() {
  var newPara = document.getElementById("tostring")
  input = ""
  newPara.value = 0;
}

function Count() {
  var arrPara = document.getElementById("result").childNodes;
  document.getElementById("result").removeChild(arrPara[Index.Count]);
}
```

```html
<label>Name</label><input id="txtName" type="text" /><br />
<p id="displayNames"></p>
<button onclick="Add()">Add</button>
<!-- add the name to 
 an array and display the name on the paragraph -->
<button onclick="Clear()">Clear</button>
<!-- clear the 
names in the array and clear the paragraph -->
<button onclick="Count()">Count</button>
<!-- count and 
display the number of times the name has been entered -->
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will clear the input value, when you clicked on the button.

```js
    function Add() {
      //create a para obj
      var newPara = document.createElement("p");

      //create the text content
      var input = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
      var newText = document.createTextNode(input);

      //attach the text to the para obj
      newPara.appendChild(newText);

      //attach the para obj to the div obj
      var myDiv = document.getElementById("result");
      myDiv.appendChild(newPara);
      
      document.getElementById('txtName').value = '';
    }

    function Clear() {
      var newPara = document.getElementById("result")
      newPara.textContent = '';
      console.log(newPara)
      newPara.value = 0;
    }

    function Count() {
      var arrPara = document.getElementById("result").childNodes;
      document.getElementById("result").removeChild(arrPara[Index.Count]);
    }
```

```html
    <label>Name</label><input id="txtName" type="text" /><br />
    <p id="displayNames"></p>
    <button onclick="Add()">Add</button>
    <!-- add the name to 
     an array and display the name on the paragraph -->
    <button onclick="Clear()">Clear</button>
    <!-- clear the 
    names in the array and clear the paragraph -->
    <button onclick="Count()">Count</button>
    <!-- count and 
    display the number of times the name has been entered -->
    <div id="result"></div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
function Clear() {
 document.getElementById("result").textContent ="";
 document.getElementById("txtName").value ="";
}
```

Comment: Please don't forget to provide at least a short explanation, how your solution works, or what the author of the original question missed. Refer to [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.